# Mono WCF Rest post multiple parameters returns error(500)

Tags: wcf, rest, mono

Recently building a RESTful WCF on linux(CLI self-hosted), the program is good under .NET but fail under Mono. 
Strictly says, function using GET and non-parameter/single-parameter POST are good, it return error 500 if post multiple parameters.

Another problem is, if pass INVALID json to mono(says, no Content-Type in header, or invalid json format), CLI will shutdown instead of throw an exception and keep on service, that's very fatal.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid comma before an end of object (4,1)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonReader.ReadContent (Boolean objectValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Please Help, THANK YOU!

First question details below

Mono Exception

```
Exception 'Element' is an invalid node type.  Line 1, position 53.   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.WebMessageFormatter.DeserializeObject (System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer serializer, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageDescription md, Boolean isWrapped, WebContentFormat fmt) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.WebMessageFormatter+WebDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior+DispatchPairFormatter.DeserializeRequest (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationInvokerHandler.BuildInvokeParams (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc, System.Object[]& parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationInvokerHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationInvokerHandler.ProcessRequest (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.BaseRequestProcessorHandler.ProcessRequestChain (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.BaseRequestProcessorHandler.ProcessRequestChain (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HandlersChain.ProcessRequestChain (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.BaseRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>      
    <services>
      <service name="Contracts.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MEXBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Contracts.IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyRestBehavior" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.99:18688/MyService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyRestBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MEXBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>    
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/> </startup></configuration>
```

Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Ping")]
        bool Ping();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate="echo")]
        string Echo(string name,string say);
    }
```

Implementation

```
 [ServiceBehavior]   
    public class MyService:IMyService
    {

        public bool Ping()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public string Echo(string name, string say)
        {
            return name + " says: " + say;
        }
    }
```

Fiddler Post

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: 192.168.1.99:18688
Content-Length: 41
Content-Type: application/json

{
"name":"Alex",
"say":"Hello World"
}
```

Fiddler Returns

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 04:31:20 GMT
Content-Length: 216
Connection: close

<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none"><Code><Value>Receiver</Value></Code><Reason><Text xml:lang="en-US">'Element' is an invalid node type.  Line 1, position 53.</Text></Reason></Fault>
```

Comment: For guys who get into this, see also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039476/how-to-debug-wcf-when-json-deserialize-fail

Comment: I had exactly the same problem when porting an asp.net hosted WCF service to mono.

Answer (score 1):

After days search, it seems a bug of mono implementation.
So if you get into this, a quick trick is keep your serialized custom class as post parameters, for other data(such as int, string, bool), post them by using WebInvoke.UriTemplate. Ya, it's the same as you use WebGet.
In this way, we can avoid(-ish) this bug when post multiple parameters.
And in most case, it's enough.

Comment: still have no idea about that force close situation. Any help?

Comment: Can you explain further? Perhaps show us an example?