# How to debug WCF when json deserialize fail?

Tags: json, wcf, serialization, mono

I've a RESTful service, but it seems buggy in MONO.

In .NET, when I past it a invalid post format, such as missing Content-Type or invalid json body format, it throw an exception and wait for next request. But in MONO, it throw unhandle exception and go down, I mean, it completely quit. This can be a fatal attack.

Unfortunately, I have no idea about how to debug it, it ain't happens on codes I wrote.

Guys any advice?? How to avoid it or catch this exception?
Thank you!

**CLI host.**

[image]

**Interface**

[image]

**Fiddler post wrong format**

[image]

**Then service is down :(**
[image]

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: 2.8.10.1-1ubuntu2.2 ,installed with mono-complete

Comment: test with mono 3.2 please

Comment: for 3.2, I double check MONO for mac and Github build, they throw a same exception when post valid json. Am I missing something, or it just worse? It mentioned security method, but my binding is webHttpBinding, without any security inside ---------------------------------------------------- `Missing method Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslServerStream::.ctor(Stream,X509Certificate,bool,bool,bool) in assembly /media/share/Debug/Mono.Security.dll, referenced in assembly /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
`

Answer (score 0):

With **@knocte** provided clue, I make it eventually.

This seems a fixed bug, but Xamarin said old version will not be patched any more.

What I do upgrade to mono3.2 (https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-3-2), now mono can handle that exception and ain't quit.

Further, you may want rebuild program with monoDevelop (https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/monodevelop-4.1.7-branch)

Thanks @knocte again, please post your clue as answer so I can vote it up ;]

P.S: Current version of mono/MD is NOT available for ubuntu apt-get, so you may clone/make them above, it works. And please notice that MD I use is NOT bleed edge one, you may switch to newer branch :]